# What features to measure for an audio streaming service

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming, internet-connection

I am setting up an audio streaming service. Users will connect to it using Wi-Fi, 2G/3G connections or even internet USB dongles. I have noticed that the internet connections with mobile connections (2G/3G/dongles) are very inconsistent and affects the user experience immensely. I want to take preventive action (let the application degrade gracefully) when faced with a bad internet connection. My question is:

1. What all characteristics should I measure to conclude that the internet connection is really bad and getting worse?

What I have so far:
I read up a few articles on this which mentioned that to stream audio, I need a minimum of 0.5 Mbps connection speed. I am currently measuring that by downloading an image from the server and measuring the time it takes for the `onload` to fire. Is there something more reliable?